# Is it possible to return the IDs of a multi row insert in SQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.5

With the statement below I can insert multiple rows into a table. If the tag exists already then nothing happens, and if it doesn't exist it creates the row.

```
INSERT INTO tags (name) VALUES ('this'),('is'),('my'),('interest'),('list'),('running'),('pokemongo'),('fighting'),('eating') ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Is is possible to return the ID of all these values whether or not they exist?

I'm using python psycopg2 with postgres 9.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished in one query using a WITH block (see PostgreSQL docs on [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)). For example:

```
WITH t1 (c1) AS ( VALUES ('this'),('is'),... ),
t2 AS (SELECT id FROM tags WHERE name IN (SELECT c1 FROM t1) ),
t3 AS (INSERT INTO tags (name) SELECT c1 FROM t1 ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id)
SELECT id from t2
UNION
SELECT id from t3;
```

You could also replace `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` with `WHERE c1 NOT IN (SELECT name FROM tags)`. This would work without relying on the conflict caused by a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO 
    tags (name) 
VALUES 
    ('this'),('is'),('my'),('interest'),('list'),('running'),('pokemongo'),('fighting'),('eating') 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING 
RETURNING ID; # <== this is what you need.
```

**Edit:**
Right, with this solution you'll only get the ids of inserted rows.

If you need all the ids, you'll have to make another query :

```
select ID from tags where name in ('this', 'is', 'my', 'interestest', 'list', '...')
```

Comment: Tried that. This only returns the ID if the row is inserted, but if that row already exists it will not return anything.

Comment: Yup, was hoping I could avoid that second query. Thanks for taking a shot though.